# Create height/ displacement map from texture?

Tags: texturing

i must add for my model a lot of hard details. I have a lot of references photo 4k, it is possible to genereate height map from picture, like this :

[image]

Comment: There are no photogrammetry tools built in blender to do a height map based on shading, or othet tools to do this using a single image like the one in your post.  For something like that probably you need to sculpt or create a height map by other means.